I can't connect to Socket.io express server through postman
My server:
const express = require('express');
const { createServer } = require('node:http');
const { join } = require('node:path');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server running at http://localhost:3000');
});

I started the server, then in Postman I did ( New -> Socket.io ) then added localhost:3000 in URL input, and clicked Connect button.
Could not connect to localhost:3000
Error:{error}
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
Request Method: GET
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Y493KXLCSfznw+AOEDX2Wg==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: localhost:3000


Please check the answer I have already given. Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78742114/9746946

Your server.js needs to add a send message to the client
And to send a message from Postman with turn-on event.
Server
Save as sever.js
const express = require('express');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { join } = require('path');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.emit('hello', { message: 'Hello from server!' });

    socket.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log('Message received from client:', data);
        socket.emit('response', { message: `Server received: ${JSON.stringify(data)}` });
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server running at http://localhost:3000');
});

Install dependencies & run it
npm install express socket.io

node server.js

Clint by Postman
URL
http://localhost:3000

Message
{ "message": "Hello I am client" }

Turn-on Event
response    : LISTEN ON


Result
Server side

Client side


Thank you for your help. I followed each step but still I have the same issue! Also, when I open the Console for debugging and hit Connect again.. the console shows empty logs!

In the console of Postman, not receive a 'Hello from server!' when it connects. It is Postman's defect. but in the Response of Postman can receive a 'response' message as attached image.
